# JavaScript - How escape quotes in a var to pass data through Json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm passing some data through Json to a Webservice.
My problem is that i'm passing html (from a tinyMCE input), so the var has content using quotes and that's giving me problems.
I'm passing the values like this:

```
 data: '{ id: "' + news_id + '", title: "' + news_title + '", body: "' + news_body + '" }',
```

Is there anyway to espace quotes in javascript, so i can send html in that news_body var?

Thanks

Comment: You can escape special characters using the "\" backslash character before the character to be escaped. For e.g. use \" to escape a double quote

Comment: `news_body.replace(/\\/g, "\\u005C").replace(/"/g, '\\u0022').replace(/'/g, "\\u0027")`  because slashes as the last character in a string also cause trouble.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than using one-off code, go with a Javascript JSON encoder (such as provided by [MooTools' JSON utility](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/JSON) or [JSON.js](http://www.JSON.org/js.html)), which will take care of encoding for you. The big browsers (IE8, FF 3.5+, Opera 10.5+, Safari & Chrome) support JSON encoding and decoding [natively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Native_JSON) via a JSON object. A well-written JSON library will rely on native JSON capabilities when present, and provide an implementation when not. The [YUI JSON library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/) is one that does this.

```
data: JSON.stringify({
  id: news_id,
  title: news_title,
  body: news_body
}),
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working properply but i've a question. I'm just using "JSON.stringify" (my browser is FF 3.6.11), so it works without the implentation of YUI JSON library. But how should i handle it for older browsers? I guess that for older browsers, it should be used YUI like this "YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify", but do i need to change anything or just using data: JSON.stringify the browser checks for JSON.stringify and if it's a old browser, it will use the YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify instead? Thanks

Comment: The sample wasn't specifically targeting YUI. If you choose to rely on YUI, you'd use its API and let it do whatever under the hood. For a lighter library, take a closer look at the open source [JSON.js](http://www.JSON.org/json2.js). It's transparent, implementing the global JSON object only if a native version doesn't exist. As more browsers support the native JSON object (it's part of the [ECMAScript 3.1](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:json_support) standard), you can eventually phase out JSON.js simply by not including it, whereas YUI would require rewriting the code.

Answer (score 19):

Use the [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

```
function esc_quot(text)
{
    return text.replace("\"", "\\\"");
}

data: '{ id: "' + esc_quot(news_id) + '", title: "' + esc_quot(news_title) + '", body: "' + esc_quot(news_body) + '" }',
```

Comment: this worked for me: var buttons = [{"type": "social"}, {"type": "embed"}, {"type": "link", "url": "http://www.saukvalley.com/"}, {"type": "email", "advertiser": "Bob's Refrigeration", "to": "advertiser@clientsite.com"}; This returns from an api, I stuff it into element's data-buttons attr, then take it out when element is clicked. Before setting element's attr I did: buttons = buttons.replace("'", "\\\"");  EDIT: stackoverflow did not escape the array object FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function below:

```
function addslashes (str) {
    return (str+'').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
}
```

For example:

```
data: '{ id: "' + addslashes(news_id) + '", title: "' + addslashes(news_title) + '", body: "' + addslashes(news_body) + '" }',
```

A lot of functions like this can be found at http://phpjs.org/functions/index

Comment: -1 -- This doesn't work as it adds slashes to both single and double quotes.  Note `"We've"` is a JS string, but `"We\'ve"` is **not** a valid JS string as you've attempted to escape a single quote in a string delimited by double quotes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2275428/457571

Answer (score -2):

if you are familiar with PHP that you can use some PHP based function form

[phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/)

They made javascript function worked as PHP library functions. You can use addslashes function from here.