# Put quotes in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSON array but it doesn't work:

```
var test = '{"chapters":[{"id":"test1", "label":"Observation", "handler":"openChapter("observation")"}]}';
```

I know the problem are the quotes around observation in the handler.

I tried this but it doesn't work either (not surprising):

```
var test = '{"chapters":[{"id":"test1", "label":"Observation", "handler":"openChapter(\"observation\")"}]}';
```

How can I do?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this post :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031324/javascript-how-escape-quotes-in-a-var-to-pass-data-through-json

Comment: Thank you, I searched but didn't find this post. :)

Comment: not exactly the case: the OP was already trying to escape the quote

Comment: What I needed is in the answers of the post but not the chosen one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape it again (`\\"`), you want the literal `\` to be in the string so `JSON.parse` can read it:

```
var test = '{"chapters":[{"id":"test1", "label":"Observation", "handler":"openChapter(\\"observation\\")"}]}';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the correct way to escape double quotes (`"`) is indeed a single backslash (`\`).

However you're creating a variable `test` as a String and not as a JSON object. If you want to create a JSON object you can do:

```
var test = {"chapters":[{"id":"test1", "label":"Observation", "handler":"openChapter(\"observation\")"}]};
```

But if you want to create it as a string for use with `JSON.parse` for example, you need to escape the backslashes now with another backslash:

```
var test = '{"chapters":[{"id":"test1", "label":"Observation", "handler":"openChapter(\\"observation\\")"}]}';
var json = JSON.parse(test);
```

JSON definition of a string:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
>   double quotes, using backslash escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do ?
As I understand it, you want to create in JavaScript datas to be sent in a JSON form ?

Then you should :

1. create an object literal
2. transform the JS object in a JSon string

Regarding JS object literals, see this webpage :
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/

You can then serialize this object to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

Another article that is a good read !
http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/