# Escaping character in json string

Tags: javascript

It is said here:

> any quotes inside the JSON have to be
>   “escaped” with a backslash in front.
>   Otherwise, JavaScript gets confused
>   about which quotes we want for display
>   and which quotes are part of the
>   programming.

but in their code snippet I can't see any escaping character is this tutorial buggy I'm confused ? :

```
var movielisttext = "{"movielist": ["Friday the 13th", "Friday the 13th Part 2", "Friday the 13th Part III", "Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter", "Friday the 13th: A New Beginning"]}";
```

My question is specifically if their article has an error or not because it amazes me that a tutorial for beginner can embed such error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is JavaScript, not JSON.

If you want JSON:

```
{
    "movielist": [
        "Friday the 13th",
        "Friday the 13th Part 2",
        "Friday the 13th Part III",
        "Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter",
        "Friday the 13th: A New Beginning"
    ]
}
```

If you want a JavaScript object

```
var movielisttext =   {
        "movielist": [
            "Friday the 13th",
            "Friday the 13th Part 2",
            "Friday the 13th Part III",
            "Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter",
            "Friday the 13th: A New Beginning"
        ]
    };
```

If you want a JavaScript string containing the JSON:

```
var movielisttext =  '{"movielist": ["Friday the 13th","Friday the 13th Part 2","Friday the 13th Part III","Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter","Friday the 13th: A New Beginning"]}';
```

or

```
var movielisttext = "{\"movielist\": [\"Friday the 13th\",\"Friday the 13th Part 2\",\"Friday the 13th Part III\",\"Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter\",\"Friday the 13th: A New Beginning\"]}";
```

Since the data itself doesn't include any `"` characters, they don't need to be escaped as far as the JSON is concerned.

Comment: And what if the data itself contains " and ' ?

Comment: If the data contains `"` characters, then they will need to be escaped. The `'` won't since they aren't delimiters. If you then want to use that as a string in JS (as per the last example) then you'll need to escape the quotes (again) and also escape (in JS) the (JSON) escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is JavaScript and not JSON, just omit the surrounding quotes:

```
var movielisttext = {"movielist": ["Friday the 13th", "Friday the 13th Part 2", "Friday the 13th Part III", "Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter", "Friday the 13th: A New Beginning"]};
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in JSON must always be wrapped in double quotes. In that example they should have formatted the JSON like this:

```
var movielisttext = '{"movielist": ["Friday the 13th", "Friday the 13th Part 2", "Friday the 13th Part III", "Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter", "Friday the 13th: A New Beginning"]}';
```

But if their intention was to create a literal Javascript object, they should have used:

```
var movielisttext = {"movielist": ["Friday the 13th", "Friday the 13th Part 2", "Friday the 13th Part III", "Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter", "Friday the 13th: A New Beginning"]};
```

In the first case, the value of `movielisttext` is a string, in the second case it's an object

Answer (score 1):

```
var movielisttext = '{"movielist": ["Friday the 13th", "Friday the 13th Part 2", "Friday the 13th Part III", "Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter", "Friday the 13th: A New Beginning"]}';
```

OR

```
var movielisttext = "{\"movielist\": [\"Friday the 13th\", \"Friday the 13th Part 2\", \"Friday the 13th Part III\", \"Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter\", \"Friday the 13th: A New Beginning\"]}";
```

Would do the trick.