# How do you represent a JSON array of strings?

Tags: json

This is all you need for valid JSON, right?

```
["somestring1", "somestring2"]
```

Comment: That's a JSON array containing two strings, yes... is there more to that question? ;)

Comment: I read something which contradicted what we're all agreeing on. So, I wanted the reality check there.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see! It's a shame you can't accept your own question as the answer :D

Comment: :)  Well, it's not just the answers that's fun. It's great people such as yourself that help make this site a fun success!

Answer (score 387, accepted):

I'll elaborate a bit more on [**ChrisR** awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5293587/274502) and bring images from his [awesome reference](http://json.org/).

A valid JSON always starts with either curly braces `{` or square brackets `[`, nothing else.

### `{` will start an `object`:

[image: left brace followed by a key string (a name that can't be repeated, in quotes), colon and a value (valid types shown below), followed by an optional comma to add more pairs of string and value at will and finished with a right brace]

```
{ "key": value, "another key": value }
```

> **Hint**: although javascript accepts single quotes `'`, JSON only takes double ones `"`.

### `[` will start an `array`:

[image: left bracket followed by value, optional comma to add more value at will and finished with a right bracket]

```
[value, value]
```

> **Hint**: spaces among elements are always ignored by any JSON parser.

### And `value` is an `object`, `array`, `string`, `number`, `bool` or `null`:

[image: Image showing the 6 types a JSON value can be: string, number, JSON object, Array/list, boolean, and null]

So yeah, `["a", "b"]` is a perfectly valid JSON, like you could [try on the link Manish pointed](http://jsonlint.com/).

Here are a few extra valid JSON examples, one per block:

```
{}

[0]

{"__comment": "json doesn't accept comments and you should not be commenting even in this way", "avoid!": "also, never add more than one key per line, like this"}

[{   "why":null} ]

{
  "not true": [0, false],
  "true": true,
  "not null": [0, 1, false, true, {
    "obj": null
  }, "a string"]
}
```

Comment: Does JSON have to have double quotes? I tried to validate the OP's string above but with single quotes on jsonlint.com and it tells me it is invalid. But it's valid when using double quotes.

Comment: @Ray as usual, that doesn't have a simple yes or no answer, although I'd say it's mostly "yeah, just go with double quotes". http://json.org tells us only about using double quotes, and most places will probably follow that. However, here's a deeper investigation about it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2275428/274502

Comment: Improve images for SO's dark theme, please.

Comment: @carloswm85 i'll leave it to you! feel free to edit the answer.  (i don't own a desktop, don't know where to set the dark theme, and don't really care... )

Answer (score 104):

Your JSON object in this case is a list. JSON is almost always an object with attributes; a set of one or more key:value pairs, so you most likely see a dictionary:

```
{ "MyStringArray" : ["somestring1", "somestring2"] }
```

then you can ask for the value of `"MyStringArray"` and you would get back a list of two strings, `"somestring1"` and `"somestring2"`.

Comment: The code example you posted is invalid, when you would try to parse that string as a json it'll throw an error/exception. The fact you say that JSON is always key/value pairs is also inherently wrong. Nothing in the JSON spec says you NEED to have key/value pairs. When talking about data transport indeed key/value pairs are the most useful structure but the string the OP posted is perfectly valid JSON: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/92ac7b

Comment: I had API's on the brain, where you want to look up the value in an array based on a key. So it would be, for an un-named array, {"1":"somestring1", "2":"somestring2"}

Answer (score 47):

Basically yes, JSON is just a javascript literal representation of your value so what you said is correct.

You can find a pretty clear and good explanation of JSON notation on http://json.org/

Answer (score 7):

```
String strJson="{\"Employee\":
[{\"id\":\"101\",\"name\":\"Pushkar\",\"salary\":\"5000\"},
{\"id\":\"102\",\"name\":\"Rahul\",\"salary\":\"4000\"},
{\"id\":\"103\",\"name\":\"tanveer\",\"salary\":\"56678\"}]}";
```

This is an example of a JSON string with `Employee` as object, then multiple strings and values in an array as a reference to `@cregox`...

A bit complicated but can explain a lot in a single JSON string.