# Passing a JS array using ajax to a function in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the [JQCloud jquery plugin](https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud) to generate a tag cloud from some Elasticsearch data. The main issue I am facing is that the data I get back is formated using the terms 'key' for tag and 'doc_count' for the number of times the tag shows up in the data. I've tried a few different ways of getting the data to parse correctly but the tag cloud never shows up on the page, nor am I getting any great information from the Chrome Dev tools console.

First call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/tags",
    type: "get",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
            $("#wordCloud").jQCloud([{text: data[0].key, weight: data[0].doc_count}, {text: data[1].key, weight: data[1].doc_count}]);
    }
  });
});
```

Second call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/tags",
    type: "get",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      $("#tagcloud").jQCloud([json]);
    }
  });
});
```

Both of these suggestions were taken from [Import a JS array using ajax to pass though to a function/plugin in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009888/import-a-js-array-using-ajax-to-pass-though-to-a-function-plugin-in-jquery).

Comment: First of all your url seems incomplete. And second, do you have any errors in console?

Comment: And secondly, synchronous requests are deprecated and never been useful, don't use it. And btw, we have no idea what data looks like. Error in console?

Comment: @lonut The URL is a local call (currently for testing). If I go to localhost:8080/tags I get back the expected JSON data. Also if I manually do some parsing I get a list back of tags but I wanted to automate the building of the cloud. My manual process is ugly

Comment: @A.Wolff No error in console which is the confusing part. I have removed the async option. The data comes in like this `[{"key": "ibm_created", "doc_count": 85}, {"key": "ibm_dedicated_public", "doc_count": 74}, {"key": "ibm_third_party", "doc_count": 40}, {"key": "p", "doc_count": 31}, {"key": "service", "doc_count": 30}, {"key": "bluemix", "doc_count": 29}, {"key": "development", "doc_count": 29}, {"key": "cloud", "doc_count": 28}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You never use synchronous Ajax. There is no justification to ever set `async: false` in an Ajax call.
2. jQuery parses JSON for you. Unless something is wrong with the server's response you don't need to call `JSON.parse()` yourself.
3. You should use the promise-based interface jQuery provides on Ajax calls, as it results higher versatility than the traditional `success` callback.
4. If your Ajax call is as simple as "GET this URL and then do something", using `$.get()` instead of `$.ajax()` will reduce the necessary lines of code.
5. Apparently `jQCloud` expects an array of objects like this: `{text: ..., weight: ...}`, but your API endpoint does not give you exactly that format. `$.map()` is there to help you transform the elements of an array.

So with all that in mind, your Ajax call could be rewritten as:

```
$.get("/tags").done(function (data) {
    var tagCloud = $.map(data, function (item) {
        return {text: item.key, weight: item.doc_count};
    });
    $("#wordCloud").jQCloud(tagCloud);
});
```

Runnable code sample below:

```js
$.mockjax({
    url: "/tags",
    responseText: [
      {"key": "ibm_created", "doc_count": 85},
      {"key": "ibm_dedicated_public", "doc_count": 74},
      {"key": "ibm_third_party", "doc_count": 40},
      {"key": "p", "doc_count": 31},
      {"key": "service", "doc_count": 30},
      {"key": "bluemix", "doc_count": 29},
      {"key": "development", "doc_count": 29},
      {"key": "cloud", "doc_count": 28}
    ]
});

$.get("/tags").done(function (data) {
    var tagCloud = $.map(data, function (item) {
      return {text: item.key, weight: item.doc_count};
    });
    $("#wordCloud").jQCloud(tagCloud);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.6.2/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud-1.0.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="wordCloud" style="width: 600px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed reply. My JS chops are not very good at the moment. The code is now producing `jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1880'` so it looks like it might not be correctly parsing the JSON data.

Comment: For me it's impossible to say why this happens. It's not because of my code, I've added a live code sample as a proof-of-concept. Run it for yourself to see.

Comment: No worries, your help is greatly appreciated. I am digging in to it now. Thanks again.

Comment: No idea why (as I am still learning JS and JQuery), but I had to add `data=JSON.parse(data);` before calling the map function.

Comment: That's because your server did not send the right content type. Set the `Content-Type: application/json` response header to inform the client of the data format. When jQuery sees that it will parse the JSON for you. That's what I meant by *"Unless something is wrong with the server's response"* in point #2 above.

Answer (score 0):

on the second one, it is not necessary add [] to json var, json var is already an array

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/tags",
    type: "get",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      $("#tagcloud").jQCloud(json);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no change in response from the console and the tag is not being generated. I am seeing if I can increase the level of error reporting in the console.

Comment: use firebug, in the tab network check your ajax call