# Attempting to insert value into JSON array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to insert a JSON entry into my table, but the catch is that this JSON string has a single quote character. The below code works perfectly when the string for mainIdea is `Its nice` but what I want is `It's nice` with an apostrophe. What would I have to change about the below code to make it work with an apostrophe? I've tried `It\'s nice` but that doesn't work either.

```
$jsonDic='{"mainName": "Steve Jobs","mainIdea": "Its nice"}';
$dictionaryToBeAdded=json_decode($jsonDic);
var_dump($dictionaryToBeAdded);
$data=mysql_query("SELECT arrayOfRequests FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
if($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
   //get json encoded arrayOfNotifs
    $decodeArray=$result['arrayOfRequests']; //this is empty
    //decode it
    $arrayOfRequests=json_decode($decodeArray);
    //add dictionary to be added
    $arrayOfRequests[]=$dictionaryToBeAdded;
    $sendBackArray=json_encode($arrayOfRequests);
    //update db
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET arrayOfRequests ='$sendBackArray' WHERE email='$email'");
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to insert a JSON entry into my table" that's the problem, db normalisation 101 - don't do that!

Comment: you should have a new table for arrayOfRequests, with each in its own 'cell' joined to the users table .

Comment: I shouldn't have JSON strings in my table? What then should I have?

Comment: You're storing encoded subfields in a database field, which makes it harder to search for values in the subfields.

Comment: Break your JSON into fields, and create matching fields in your db. This may involve new tables in order to normalize the data.

Comment: Oh god..I'm new to MySQL..what's wrong with my method? Will it slow down performance or something?

Comment: Yeah, it's gonna bite you. Lemme look for some db tutorials...

Comment: A JSON entry can be seen as an entity of its own. Inserting one entity means that your database design is at 1NF, or 1 Normal Form.

Comment: poor performance, poor maintenance, poor scalability ...

Comment: hey @mohabitar - try using MySQL Workbench's EER Diagram designer it'll help.

Comment: So I should have a table called arrayOfRequests, but I don't understand then what this table should have?

Comment: @mohabitar, google "normalizing data" and learn from some tutorials. Here's one to get you started. It's using Access, but the concepts are the same in mySql: http://www.fabalou.com/Access/General/Normalization.asp. The basic idea is you have a table for each type of object or idea, and you link them together with record Ids.

Comment: See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response

Comment: Ok I know this is crazy..but how important is this? How big of a mistake will I be making if I keep my current structure? The most any user will have is probably say 500 dictionaries in the array.

Comment: o geze do not put json into your database. if you have a one to many relationship of users to dictionary entries, dictionary entries should have it's own table, and the records should be related to each other by a key field. for instance user would have a unique "id" field, and dictionary entries would have an indexed field called "user_id" or something like that. then you can use query with joins to pull up all the records for both tables.

Comment: @mohabitar, you'll be sooooooooorrrryyyy! It's not much more effort to do it right. Think of it this way: How are you going to query to do the following: Get a list of all users with mainName equal to the name of another user? Or how about, Get a list of users with mainIdea containing "automobile" (upper or lowercase) and sort the mainNames that match those mainIdeas. Finally, a good reason to do it right is that apps *always* grow. *Always*.

Comment: Also, you'll never be able to index on the fields mainName or mainIdea, which will make searching on those fields even more slow.

Comment: I've posted a new question about this, in case any one wants to give a full answer and earn some points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321399/normalizing-mysql-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your data before you attempt to use it in a database query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET arrayOfRequests ='$sendBackArray' WHERE email='$email'");
// ---------------------------------------------^                            ^
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Imagine what would happen if `$sendBackArray` contains `', email ='` and `$email` contains `' OR '' = '`.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET arrayOfRequests ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($sendBackArray) . "' WHERE email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your slash as well:

```
$jsonDic='{"mainName": "Steve Jobs","mainIdea": "It\\\'s nice"}';
```

Comment: This is giving me NULL for var_dump($dictionaryToBeAdded);

Comment: Actually, JSON requires *double*-quoted keys. See http://json.org. Also they're not invalid for javascript.

Comment: @jonathanm - yep just realised.

Comment: I didn't create that string by hand..it was an Objective C dictionary which was encoded to JSON with JSONKit