# Normalizing MySQL data

Tags: mysql, normalization

I'm new to MySQL, and just learned about the importance of data normalization. My database has a simple structure:

I have 1 table called `users` with fields:

```
userName (string)
userEmail (string)
password (string)
requests (an array of dictionaries in JSON string format)
data (another array of dictionaries in JSON string format)
deviceID (string)
```

Right now, this is my structure. Being very new to MySQL, I'm really not seeing why my above structure is a bad idea? Why would I need to normalize this and make separate tables? That's the first question-why? (Some have also said not to put JSON in my table. Why or why not?)

The second question is how? With the above structure, how many tables should I have, and what would be in each table?

**Edit:**
So maybe normalization is not absolutely necessary here, but maybe there's a better way to implement my data field? The `data` field is an array of dictionaries: each dictionary is just a note item with a few keys (title, author, date, body). So what I do now is, which I think might be inefficient, every time a user composes a new note, I send that note from my app to PHP to handle. I get the JSON array of dictionaries already part of that user's data, I convert it to a PHP array, I then add to the end of this array the new note, convert the whole thing back to JSON, and put it back in the table as an array of dictionaries. And this process is repeated every time a new note is composed. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe a user's data should be a table, with each row being a note-but I'm not really sure how this would work?

Comment: How are you utilizing the JSON data?

Comment: It's for an iPhone note taking app. Data is just the user's array of notes in JSON format..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to all your questions really depends on what the JSON data is for, and whether you'll ever need to use some property of that data to determine which rows are returned.

If your data truly has no schema, and you're really just using it to store data that will be used by an application that knows how to retrieve the correct row by some other criteria (such as one of the other fields) every time, there's no reason to store it as anything other than exactly as that application expects it (in this case, JSON).

If the JSON data DOES contain some structure that is the same for all entries, and if it's useful to query this data directly from the database, you would want to create one or more tables (or maybe just some more fields) to hold this data.

As a practical example of this, if the data fields contains JSON enumerating services for that user in an array, and each service has a unique id, type, and price, you might want a separate table with the following fields (using your own naming conventions):

```
serviceId (integer)
userName (string)
serviceType (string)
servicePrice (float)
```

And each service for that user would get it's own entry.  You could then query for users than have a particular service, which depending on your needs, could be very useful.  In addition to easy querying, indexing certain fields of the separate tables can also make for very QUICK queries.

Update: Based on your explanation of the data stored, and the way you use it, you probably do want it normalized.  Something like the following:

```
# user table
userId (integer, auto-incrementing)
userName (string)
userEmail (string)
password (string)
deviceID (string)

# note table
noteId (integer, auto-incrementing)
userId (integer, matches user.userId)
noteTime (datetime)
noteData (string, possibly split into separate fields depending on content, such as subject, etC)

# request table
requestId (integer, auto-incrementing)
userId (integer, matches user.userId)
requestTime (datetime)
requestData (string, again split as needed)
```

You could then query like so:

```
# Get a user
SELECT * FROM user WHERE userId = '123';
SELECT * FROM user WHERE userNAme = 'foo';

# Get all requests for a user
SELECT * FROM request WHERE userId = '123';
# Get a single request
SELECT * FROM request WHERE requestId = '325325';

# Get all notes for a user
SELECT * FROM note WHERE userId = '123';
# Get all notes from last week
SELECT * FROM note WHERE userId = '123' AND noteTime > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK;

# Add a note to user 123
INSERT INTO note (noteId, userId, noteData) VALUES (null, 123, 'This is a note');
```

Notice how much more you can do with normalized data, and how easy it is?  It's trivial to locate, update, append, or delete any specific component.

Comment: My application would never really need to do any fancy searches or sorting in the db, it just needs to retrieve the JSON data string for a specific email address, convert it to an array, and the app will know what to do with it. So say in my above table I have 500,000 users, and I want to retrieve the data field for email:steve@gmail.com. Will the performance of this query be affected by whether my data is normalized or not? Or is my current structure fine for that situation?

Comment: Definitely normalize. With relational databases, if you don't know whether to normalize or not to normalize, you should definitely normalize.

Comment: Can you explain the difference in this query whether my data is normalized or not?

Comment: If you truly will never need to do anything beyond query by email, then there's no reason to normalize beyond what you have.  For that matter, you could just shove every other field besides email into the same JSON structure, since you'll never need to query then directly anyway.  The problem is, very few people know EXACTLY what you'll need later when first designing an application.  In that case, you're better off erroring on the side of caution and at least normalizing the easy stuff.

Comment: @mohabitar; Your edit suggests that one of the operations your app will be doing is adding one item to the array of dictionaries. Other operations  (I assume) will be removing one item or changing one item. Then, normalization will definitely benefit your application. Your devices will just need to send simple `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` statements that will be one-small-row wide (one item wide) and not one-big-row wide (one array wide).

Comment: Ya I think you're right..but I don't understand..if I have a seperate table for data alone, and I have 50 users with 50 notes each, then I would have 1 table with 2500 rows? Or how would this table be structured?

Comment: When I delete an email from my Xmail account, I don't want my app to send a 7GB `UPDATE email SET json = @NewUpdatedData WHERE username='ypercube'` when a 60-bytes `DELETE email WHERE username = 'ypercube' AND email_id = 691756` could do the same.

Comment: But so would that be how the table would be structured? It would be just 1 table with data rows for all users? So if there are 50 users with 50 notes, in 1 table alone it would have 2500 rows? But then one user's note can be in say the 3rd row of the table, while his next note is at row 2300. This is ok?

Comment: Yes, this is ok. One table for users (50 rows) and one for notes (2500 rows). The columns needed depend on your JSON structures.

Comment: @kbenson thank you for taking the time to write that! You just cleared up so much for me. I should be able to take it from here. Thank you!

Comment: One thing I'm not seeing: let's say a user has 500 notes, and I'm using my old basic non-relational method, where a user has just an array of notes. If I want to get all this user's notes, I just have to find this user, and get his array. But now since each note is a row in a table, and I have say 500,000 rows and I want to get all this one user's notes, wouldn't it have to search through all 500,000 rows to get all the user's notes?

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is a philosophy. Some people think it fits their database approach, some don't. Many modern database solutions even focus on denormalization to improve speeds.

Normalization often doesn't improve speed. However, it greatly improves the simplicity of accessing and writing data. For example, if you wanted to add a request, you would have to write a completely new JSON field. If it was normalized, you could simply add a row to a table.

In normalization, "array of dictionaries in JSON string format" is always bad. Array of dictionaries can be translated as list of rows, which is a table.

If you're new to databases: NORMALIZE. Denormalization is something for professionals.

Comment: re `normalization doesn't improve speed` -- that *definitely* needs to be qualified.  Sometimes it's true, sometimes it's not.

Comment: Normalization and speed... Ah the age old debate. if i had a table with the 50 text fields that could be normalized into a few tables, it will definitely be faster to normalized if i am querrying for only like1 of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

A main benefit of normalization is to eliminate redundant data, but since each user's data is unique to that user, there is no benefit to splitting this table and normalizing. Furthermore, since the front-end will employ the dictionaries as JSON objects anyway, undue complication and a decrease in performance would result from trying to decompose this data.

Okay, here is a normalized mySQL data-model. **Note:** you can separate authors and titles into two tables to further reduce data redundancy. You can probably use similar techniques for the "requests dictionaries":

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
  UID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  userName varchar(255) UNIQUE,
  password varchar(30),
  userEmail varchar(255) UNIQUE,
  deviceID varchar(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE BOOKS(
  BKID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  FKUSERS int, 
  Title varchar(255),
  Author varchar(50)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE BOOKS
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKUSERS)
    REFERENCES USERS(UID);

CREATE TABLE NOTES(
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  FKUSERS int, 
  FKBOOKS int,
  Date date,
  Notes text
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE NOTES
  ADD FOREIGN KEY BKNO (FKUSERS)
    REFERENCES USERS(UID);
ALTER TABLE NOTES
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (FKBOOKS)
    REFERENCES BOOKS(BKID);
```

Comment: Oh. So there can be many notes for each user and and multiple users can specify the same title and author? Can users modify an existing note or can notes only be added?

Comment: Each user has their own private notes. They can indeed modify, delete, and add notes.

Comment: Thank you for your update. It has been really helpful with trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I will abstract out the class that handles this table. Then keep the data normalized. if in future, the data access patterns changes and i need to normalized the data, i css just do so with less impact on the program. I just need to change the class that handles this set of data to query the normalized tables , but return the data as if the database structure never changed.