# JSON value with apostrophe

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, apostrophe

I have an element with a rel attribute that contains a JSON string, something like:

```
rel='{"id":"#id#","name":"#name#"}'
```

Then, in my javascript code, I use `$.parseJSON` to parse this data. This works correctly - besides for cases where `name` contains an apostrophe. I've tried using `jsStringFormat`, a coldfusion `replace` that replaces all single quotes with escaped single quotes, etc, but I can't seem to hit on a correct solution. I know this is probably simple, but how do I get the code to correctly pass values with apostropes/single quotes using json?

This code works, but eliminates the apostrophes which I'd like to preserve:

```
rel='{"id":"#id#","name":"#replace(name,"'","","all")#"}'
```

This does not work:

```
rel='{"id":"#id#","name":"#replace(name,"'","\'","all")#"}'
```

Nor does:

```
rel='{"id":"#id#","name":"#replace(name,"'","\\\'","all")#"}'
```

Or:

```
rel='{"id":"#id#","name":"#replace(name,"'","&quot;","all")#"}'
```

Or:

```
rel='{"id":"#id#","name":"#jsStringFormat(name)#"}'
```

Comment: To properly escape double quotes in HTML attributes use `&quot;`

Comment: Why can't you just use [serializeJson](http://cfdocs.org/serializeJson)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of playing around, I finally got this to work :)

```
rel='{"id":"#id#","name":"#replace(name,"'","&##39;","all")#"}'
```

Comment: This answer is a hack and shouldn't be the recommended solution. It solves the issue with the apostrophe, but still allows other invalid characters in the output.  e.g. if "name" has an ampersand in it. The correct answer is to properly encode strings for the context they are being used in.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is because you are dealing with a string in two contexts.  You need to make sure that the string is safe in both.

**JSON string:**

The easiest way to make the code JSON safe is to use [SerializeJSON function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79fa.html) to  convert a ColdFusion object into valid JSON.

Thus your code could become:

```
rel='#SerializeJSON({"id"=Variables.id,"name"=Variables.name})#'
```

**HTML attribute string:**

The next context that you need to deal with is that you want the string to be a valid html attribute value.

In ColdFusion 10 you would handle this with the [EncodeForHTMLAttribute function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WS932f2e4c7c04df8f-6f7941141353e2963af-7ffe.html).

```
rel='#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(SerializeJSON({"id"=Variables.id,"name"=Variables.name}))#'
```

If you're using something prior to CF10 then using the ESAPI encoder is your best bet.  (This was included with [patches on some versions of ColdFusion](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/788.cfm))

```
rel='#CreateObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI").encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute(SerializeJSON({"id"=Variables.id,"name"=Variables.name}))#'
```

I personally use a helper CFC to deal with ESAPI encoder in CF9, so CreateObject is only called once and reused for all uses of its methods.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, escape single quotes in strings with `\`.

In HTML, you should really use double quotes for attributes though, and escape the double quotes, for example:

```
rel="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;#id#&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;#name#&quot;}"
```

Comment: I'm using a coldfusion variable, not a literal. The pound signs denote the variable

Comment: @froadie: I've changed the example to reflect your variables.

Comment: that doesn't work, I don't think it's correct JSON syntax

Comment: If you view the HTML source, what output are you getting from coldfusion?

Comment: it terminates the entire JSON string at the apostrophe in the name

Comment: Apostrophes are valid in JSON and do not need to be escaped. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response

Comment: @Spolto Apostrophes are valid in JSON, but should be escaped in an HTML attribute.  That's the issue that froadie is experiencing.