# Why jQuery.parseJSON does not accept newlines?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Ok so I've been dealing with a PHP 5.3 server returning a hand-made JSON (because in 5.3 there's no `JSON_UNESCAPE_UNICODE` in the `json_encode` function) and after reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275428/276451) and making some tests, I think I've found a problem in jQuery's `parseJSON` function.

Suppose I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "hello": "hi\nlittle boy?"
}
```

If you check it using [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) you can see it's valid JSON. However, if you try the following, you get an error message:

```
$(function(){
    try{
        $.parseJSON('{ "hello": "hi\nlittle boy?" }');
    } catch (exception) {
        alert(exception.message);
    }    
});​
```

[Link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8t89/).

I've opened a [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12666) at jQuery, because I think it's a proper bug. What do you think?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a bug, it has to do with how the string literal is handled in JavaScript.  When you have:

```
'{ "hello": "hi\nlittle boy?" }'
```

...your string will get parsed into:

```
{ "hello": "hi
little boy?" }
```

...*before* it is passed to `parseJSON()`.  And that clearly is not valid JSON, since the `\n` has been converted to a literal newline character in the middle of the "hi little boy?" string.

You want the '`\n`' sequence to make it to the `parseJSON()` function before being converted to a literal newline.  For that to happen, it needs to be escaped *twice* in the literal string.  Like:

```
'{ "hello": "hi\\nlittle boy?" }'
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/m8t89/2/

Comment: Mmm I'm not really sure about it not being a bug though. Despite how string literals are handled in JavaScript, jQuery should check if a character is a newline character and accept it, because it's possible to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/UTVcW/

Comment: @JoseTomasTocino - They could do that, yes.  But then their JSON parser would not be following the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/), which explicitly excludes literal "control characters" (such as 'carriage return' and 'linefeed') from its definition of a valid string.  So if this is a bug, it's a bug in the spec, not a bug in jQuery's (or anybody else's) implementation of it.

Comment: Well, in the JSON Spec, the [string sequence](http://www.json.org/string.gif) seems to accept "\n" characters (that would actually be two characters, I get it). It would be sensible to add an exception in jQuery's parser so if there's a single-character "\n", they associate it to the two-chracter "\n" and accept the incoming string. I can't think of any case in which acting otherwise could be harmful.

Comment: Ok, looks like both Chrome and firefox javascript engines behave the same way, saying the json is erroneous. This is pretty much a lost battle.