# How to type the prime ( ' ) symbol in a string?

Tags: javascript

What is the proper syntax to display 25' as output description?

**Example:**

```
var sizeData = [            
    {description:'Recommended sizes listed below', value:'', text:'Select Size'},                   
    {description:'Boat < 25 &prime;, value:'size0', text:'Size 0'},
    {description:'25-35 Foot Boat', value:'size2', text:'Size 2'},
    {description:'40-45 Foot Boat', value:'size3', text:'Size 3'},
];
```

Comment: That is not [JSON](http://json.org/)!

Comment: The prime character is a distinct Unicode character. You can use it inside a singe-quote encapsulated string normally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response

Answer (score 3):

In a JSON file, where all strings are delimited with double quotes, you can just write apostrophes.

In a JavaScript object literal, where you can delimit strings with apostrophes as well, you then will need to escape them with a backslash: `'\''` (dobule quote delimiters: just `"'"`).

The [prime symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) - which is different from the [apostrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) you typed - can be inserted without harm. Depending on the encoding of your file, you might need to write it a bit different. In HTML you can replace it with the [entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_entities) `&prime;`, in both JSON and JavaScript you can replace it with the escape sequence `\u2032` if you do not want to use the recommended UTF-8 character `′`.

Comment: To be clear, escaping is needed *if* you chose to use the single-quotes for that value... if using the double quotes there is no need for escaping the single quote within.

Comment: It should be noted that in JSON the keys should be enclosed in double quotes too.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Since in JSON keys *are* strings, the same rules apply to them

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
foo: '25′'
```

Notice that the [prime character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2032/index.htm) and the [apostrophe character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm) are two different Unicode characters. You can put the prime character inside a single-quote encapsulated string normally.

Btw, above the prime character is printed in monospace font. This is how it looks in sans-serif:

25′, and 25′′

Answer (score 0):

var sizeData = [
    {description:\'Recommended sizes listed below\', value:\'\', text:\'Select Size\'},
    {description:\'Boat < 25 ′, value:\'size0\', text:\'Size 0\'}
];

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose a (') using a "". Basically like this " ' ".