# How automatic escape quotes in json (C#)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

From server I get json. Json is very big. I show litle piece of this

```
{
      "id": "9429531978965160",
      "name": "Morning in  "Paris"",  // json.net cannot deserialize this line, because line have no escaped quotes.
     "alias": "ThisAlias"
}
```

Comment: If you're receiving that text as quoted, you're not receiving JSON. You're receiving a bunch of characters that is vaguely JSON-like, but which is not valid (and cannot be reasonably be parsed). The problem needs to be fixed at the source, which is whatever is generating that mess. The `name` property should be output like this: `"name": "Morning in  \"Paris\"",` More: http://json.org

Comment: Looks like you need to get the server to generate proper json

Comment: invalid JSON from server, more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2275428/169714

Comment: your are right. Server get application/javascript. And how it convert to json???

Answer (score 1):

It's not just that the output you are receiving is non-standard json, it's broken in such a way that it's not a well-defined language and doesn't parse unambiguously even in the simple cases.  How should you parse `{"a": "A", "b": "B"}`?  One way is as legal json.  Another valid parse is a single property `a` with the value `"A\", \"b\": \"B"`.

As others have said, the best resolution is to fix the server so that it no longer outputs invalid garbage.  If that's not an option, you'll have to write your own parser.  A normal parser would declare an syntax error at the 'P' in "Paris".  Your parser could back up to the last quote token and try to treat it as if it were escaped.  The next syntax error is at the second of the consecutive quotes, and again it could back up and treat the quote token as if it were escaped.  If there are any other ways in which the input deviates from legal json you'll need to handle those as well.

If you're not familiar with parsers, this will take a while.  And when you're done you'll have a parser that recognizes a poorly-specified and almost totally useless language, which is to say that it will largely be a waste of time.  Do what you can to fix it on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the server side that generates invalid JSON.

You could try writing a regex that fixes this (searches for any quotes in between the third and last). Just note that there might be many other issues with the JSON, like newlines that are not escaped etc.

Comment: in this json error only escapes. I tested it in online json validator

Comment: How convert javascript liked json to json?