# Pass a css properties array to the .css method

Tags: jquery, css, methods

I create an array from splitting a string which have the css properties and then I pass the array to the css method but it doesn't work.

```
var cssString = "'top':'25px', 'height':'400px'";
var cssArray = new Array;
cssArray = cssString.split(",");
$("#div").css(cssArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your string in JSON object then pass it `.css()` method.

```
var cssString = "'top':'25px', 'height':'400px'".replace(/'/g, '\"'); // replace single quotes
var jsonStrring = "{" + cssString + "}"; //Create a string in JSON format
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonStrring); //Convert to JSON object
$("#div").css(jsonObject); //Pass JSON object
```

Comment: I was thinking in that direction too, but it's not valid JSON syntax. "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: @Guffa, Thanks for pointing out fixed problem (with single quotes) http://jsfiddle.net/7trvW/

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer, it works perfectly! I thought that the css method was working with normal arrays. One last question: Why is it necessary replace the single quotes? I need to read more about json.

Comment: @user2409347, Read [jQuery single quote in JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response) Proper reason is provide. To sum up "single quotes is not allowed."

Answer (score 0):

If your string was valid JSON, you could parse it into an object and call `$("#div").css(cssJsonObject);`.

Since it's not valid JSON (no curly brackets, and the wrong quotes), you'll need to either make sure your string is valid JSON and parse it accordingly, or start with a valid javascript object in the first place, like:

```
var cssObject = {top:"25px", height:"400px"};
$("#div").css(cssObject);
```