# mongodb aggregation: group by _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

After aggregation I got this result. The _id field is each class's id and I applied {$group:{_id:"$_id", .....

```
[{ _id: 54c977314f5293b74ea54f96, subject: 'math' }, score: 73.5335 },
{ _id: 54c977314f5293b74ea54f96, subject: 'science' }, score: 56.2192 },
{ _id: 54c977314f5293b74ea54f96, subject: 'history' }, score: 82.8821 },
{ _id: 54c974bdff0d993b4ecf34ce, subject: 'math' }, score: 68.2598 },
{ _id: 54c974bdff0d993b4ecf34ce, subject: 'science' }, score: 77.8712 },
{ _id: 54c974bdff0d993b4ecf34ce, subject: 'history' }, score: 71.9218 },
                                 ...                                  ]
```

The problem is _id value is not string type. so when I send JSON to client, it says malformed JSON.

How can I get string type _id? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to include the `_id`? What are you doing with the `_id`? You could suppress it from the output. An ObjectId is an ObjectId - it's not a string or any type that can be directly represented in JSON and you'd need to decide on a strategy for representing it as a JSON type.

Comment: You can use the toString() method to convert the _id to a string before sending it to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't form the JSON string yourself. 
Use `JSON.stringify( output_from_aggregation )`.

However, if you don't want do that, then do this.

- Make sure to form strings wrapped in double quotes (`"`), and not single quotes (`'`). Strings in single quotes are invalid in JSON.
- You need to wrap the _id value in a string. It's an invalid hex number since it's too large to parse.

#### Old code:

```
...
{ _id: 54c974bdff0d993b4ecf34ce, subject: 'science' }, score: 77.8712 },
...
```

#### New Code:

```
...
{ _id: "54c974bdff0d993b4ecf34ce", subject: "science" }, score: 77.8712 },
...
```

More info:

- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [jQuery single quote in JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, _id is automatically generated and is of BSON (Binary JSON) type.
You can manually choose _id as a String and write its value. For example

```
db.collection.insert( { _id: "10", item: "box", qty: 20 } )
```

you can see documentation for more detail on _id field
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/

Comment: yeah, I know. but the _id's are already ObjectId type and in my opinion changing them to string type is more challenging.

Comment: You can use valueOf() method to find value of the ObjectId() object as a lowercase hexadecimal string. Example : ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").valueOf()  it's value is: 507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e