# validating JSON code

Tags: json, validation

the following bit of JSON code is seen as invalid in two independent validators (but I have a suspicion that some validators would accept it). Since I know very little about JSON, could anybody please point out the mistake?

```
{
     "cz": "CZ 51740018",
     "bod_id": "30476",
     "N": "",
     "E": "",
     "nazev": "ICE\'N\'GO\! CZ s.r.o.", // <-- this line probably has a mistake
     "adresa": "Pražská 2116/12a, 46601 Jablonec nad Nisou",
     "ddata": "",
     "typ_id": "0",
     "zdroj": ""
}
```

Comment: As you use doublequotes theres no need to escape the singlequotes. Right?

Comment: Some validators will require single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSLint tells me the backslashes are the problem (like ggzone said)

```
{
    "cz" : "CZ 51740018",
    "bod_id" : "30476",
    "N" : "",
    "E" : "",
    "nazev" : "ICE'N'GO! CZ s.r.o.", // <-- fixed the mistake
    "adresa" : "Pražská 2116/12a, 46601 Jablonec nad Nisou",
    "ddata" : "",
    "typ_id" : "0",
    "zdroj" : ""
}
```

If you need to keep the escaped special characters in place, you might try double escaping them like this :

```
{
    "nazev" : "ICE\\'N\\'GO\\! CZ s.r.o.", // <-- this is fine too.
}
```

Comment: escaping the single quotes was indeed the problem, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually in the bold text. Are you trying to escape a single quote? If that's what you are trying to do, you don't have to escape single quotation in JSON just remove the backslashes and it should be correct.
check this out [jQuery single quote in JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response)