# How to pass json data from C# controller to angular js?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

How to pass json data from C# controller to angular js ? I want to pass json from controller to angular js. I tried different but none of them worked. See my code below,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/adnActions/getJson")
    .success(function (response) { alert(response.records); $scope.names = response.records; });
});
```

C# controller code

```
 public async Task<string> getJson()
    {
                 data="{'records':[ {'Name':'Alfreds Futterkiste','City':'Berlin','Country':'Germany'}, {'Name':'Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados','City':'México D.F.','Country':'Mexico'}]}";
       return data;    

    }
```

but am unable to get the data in angular js controller
below is the error raised in console, 
"Error: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

how to fix this? Whats the problem here?

Comment: I wonder if, since your method is marked async but you're not awaiting, if the object being serialized is the Task<string>.ToString() rather than your intended JSON payload. Can you do a network capture and see what the actual response from your service is at the browser? This might reveal the problem.

Comment: Guessing here, but what content type does your API return? Does it need to be application/json for Angular to pick it up?

Comment: It should be Json format so that i can give that returned value to my angular variable. ($scope.names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is because the format of your JSON.  You are using single quotes vs double.  Valid JSON uses [double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response).

Here is what i get when i run your json i have changed the response to be HttpResponseMessage and explicitly set the response content type to eliminate this as an issue.  Based on your error being on Javascript side i think your problem is your single quotes in your JSON.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetJsonSingle()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("{'records':[ {'Name':'Alfreds Futterkiste','City':'Berlin','Country':'Germany'}, {'Name':'Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados','City':'México D.F.','Country':'Mexico'}]}")
        };

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        return result;
        }
```

results in:

[image: busted]

While double quotes:

```
     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetJsonDouble()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("{\"records\":[ {\"Name\":\"Alfreds Futterkiste\",\"City\":\"Berlin\",\"Country\":\"Germany\"}, {\"Name\":\"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados\",\"City\":\"México D.F.\",\"Country\":\"Mexico\"}]}")
        };

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        return result;
    }
```

works correctly:

[image: correct]

Answer (score 0):

use  EF to create json object and use web api controller to GET(select),PUT(update),POST(insert),DELETE(delete) data

```
 public class CarsController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly ICarRepository _cars = new CarRepository();
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<Car> Get()
        {
            return _cars.GetAllCars();
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public Car Get(int id)
        {
            Car c = _cars.GetCar(id);
            if (c == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return c;
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public Car Post(Car car)
        {
            return _cars.AddCar(car);
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public Car Put(Car car)
        {
            if (!_cars.Update(car))
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return car;
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public Car Delete(int id)
        {
            Car c = _cars.GetCar(id);
            _cars.Remove(id);
            return c;
        }
    } 
}
```