# json request body parse

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

```
"name": "body-parser", "version": "1.13.3",
```

my json request body is`{user:'guow'}` , but express request.body is `{ '{user:\'guow\'}': '' }`

This is configuration of my express app

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded //
app.use(multer());
```

I am sending request with jquery and my code is

```
$.ajax({ type: “POST”, url: “/login”, cache: false, dataType: 'json', data:“{user:'guow'}"});
```

Will someone encountered such a problem?

Comment: How do you post your request?

Comment: jQuery$.ajax({  
              type: “POST”,
              url: “/login”,
              cache: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              data:“{user:'guow'}"});

Comment: how did you configure your body-parser to your express app. Add the configuration code.

Comment: var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//var multer = require('multer');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
//app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data

Comment: @user891530 you don't need to send a stringified object. Just use: `$.ajax({ type: “POST”, url: “/login”, cache: false, dataType: 'json', data: {user: "grow"});`

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Thank you, this is right, but why?

Comment: @user891530 that's because jQuery will automatically serialize an object to string for you. In your code it serialized a string which doesn't give any effect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
         url: "/login",
         cache: false,
         dataType: 'json',
         data:{"user":"guow"}
      });
```

Comment: If you want to send JSON, then you have to send a string. The previous value was just invalid JSON. If you pass jQuery an object then it will send www-form-urlencoded encoded data, not JSON.

Comment: @Quentin: you mean data:JSON.stringify({"user":"guow"}) would have been the correct way?

Comment: That or manually constructing a string that is valid JSON. You'd also need to specify the content-type correctly since jQuery's default is wrong for JSON.

Comment: Re latest edit: Setting the content type to JSON while setting the value of `data` to an Object isn't going to work. You have to assign a JSON encoded string to `data`.

Comment: @Quentin If you know the proper correct answer, Why don't you add or edit the answer.

Comment: @Mahesh — I'm not familiar enough with Express to give a confident answer (and even less so without the information that was only very recently edited into the question). I am familiar enough with jQuery to spot when an answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert in node.js, but I had similar problem in other context.

I believe you should change ' (single quote) in " (double quote) in your json request, as single quotes will be interpreted as literals. json wants that request to be stated like {"user":"guow"}.

just my two cents.

Also, the accepted answer from this other question matters:

[jQuery single quote in JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response)

Comment: The result is the same.

Comment: as I stated, I am no expert in node.js. Actually I would have posted a comment but I cannot yet because of low rep. it also looks like your request body became a key in express request.body. I agree you should check the way you post the request.

Comment: may I ask the exact reason for downvote? just for curiosity. lowering my rep does not help me ever be able to post comments instead of answers when a comment might have helped. no pun intended

Comment: thank mate, now my life on this community will improve (and so will my answers!)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your code the whole body `{user:'guow'}` is set as a string key for the object. Note the single quotes around the original object `{ '{user:\'guow\'}': '' }`

You need to check how your object is passed to the send function. Something like

```
res.send({user:'guow'});
```

Should be fine.