# How to json_encode on json data that has single-quote?

Tags: php, mysql, json

After fetching from the DB, I perform a print json_encode on it as below

```
function queryPrintJson($cnx, $query) {
    $rows=queryReturnJsonArray($cnx, $query);       
    print json_encode($rows, JSON_HEX_APOS);
}

function queryReturnJsonArray($cnx, $query) {
    $result=mysqli_query($cnx, $query) or die ("Can't execute query!");
    $rows = array();

    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
        $rows[] = $obj;
    }
    $result->close();
    return $rows;
}
```

It doesn't print anything. After debugging i.e. var_dump etc, simplify the query, reducing the data result... I can't to realize this is because one of the field (description) contain single quote (i.e. ') in it. With the existence of this single quote, I can't get my `json_encode` working.

Is there anyway to work around this, than to go to the database and manually edit all the data with escape character? Perhaps a way to replace the auto-escape the single-quote after it got retrieve from the db?

*UPDATED*
Apparently this is not due to single quote issue, but a special single quote call right single quote mark. Check `http://unicodelookup.com/#’'/1`

Found another one , which is – and -. Refer to `http://unicodelookup.com/#–-/1`. The first one will cause the json_encode not to return anything.

Another one is “ and ". `http://unicodelookup.com/#“"/1`

Comment: Show us where you got $rows from.

Comment: Please show us the format of the value you fetched from the database

Comment: An example of a field is having as below , `EPCC’s Main Auditorium`. Notice the after the EPCC, there's single quote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response see this answer

Comment: Validate your json output with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Found out that apparently the issue is not 'single quote' i.e. apostrophe, but right single quotation mark. They are ’  that is not working, while ' that is working. Refer to http://unicodelookup.com/#’'/1 to get the info.

Answer (score 1):

Single Quote shouldn't affect your `json_encode()` function.

Example.

```
$person = array(
    "name" => "I don't know my Name",
    "email" => "I don't know my Email as well"
);   
print_r($person);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [name] => I don't know my Name
    [email] => I don't know my Email as well
)
```

and

```
echo json_encode($person);
```

Output

```
{"name":"I don't know my Name","email":"I don't know my Email as well"}
```

Comment: Thanks, this enlighten me to check further. Apparently the character in the db is not the usual single quote, but right single quotation mark. They are ’  that is not working, while ' that is working. Refer to http://unicodelookup.com/#’'/1 to get the info.