# Dealing with mis-escaped characters in JSON

Tags: python, json, string, file-io, data-structures

I am reading a JSON file into Python which contains escaped single quotes (*\'*). This leads to all kinds of hiccups, as nicely discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response). However, I could not find anything on how to **address** the issue. I just did a

```
newstring=originalstring.replace(r"\'", "'")
```

and things worked out. But this seems rather ugly. I could not really find much material on how to deal with this kind of thing (creating an exception, or something) in the json [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) either.

- Is there a good, clean procedure for such an issue?

Going back to the source is not possible, unfortunately.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `\'` character sequence is indeed invalid JSON, because there is no such escape sequence in JSON. How did you produce this output in the first place?

Comment: Hi Martijn, I did not produce it at all, just working with what was given to me.  Apparently it was created with "Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin".

Comment: Do consider filing a bug report to that project in that case.

Comment: Sure, I just thought it was probably a problem with user settings (I've never worked with PHPMyAdmin). This seems like a straightforward thing for a *json plugin* to get right? I'll look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JSON standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) defines specific set of [valid 2-character escape sequences](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7): `\\`, `\/`, `\"`, `\b`, `\r`, `\n`, `\f` and `\t`, and one 4-character escape sequence to define any Unicode codepoint, `\uhhhh` (`\u` plus 4 hex digits). Any other sequence of backslash plus other character is *invalid JSON*.

If you have a JSON source you can't fix otherwise, the only way out is to remove the invalid sequences, like you did with `str.replace()` even if it is a little fragile (it'll *break* when there is an even backslash sequence preceding the quote).

You could use a regular expression too, where you remove *any* backslashes not used in a valid sequence:

```
fixed = re.sub(r'(?<!\\)\\(?!["\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})', r'', inputstring)
```

This won't catch out an odd-count backslash sequence like `\\\` but will catch anything else:

```
>>> import re, json
>>> broken = r'"JSON string with escaped quote: \' and various other broken escapes: \a \& \$ and a newline!\n"'
>>> json.loads(broken)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 34 (char 33)
>>> json.loads(re.sub(r'(?<!\\)\\(?!["\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})', r'', broken))
"JSON string with escaped quote: ' and various other broken escapes: a & $ and a newline!\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

The right thing would be to fix whatever is creating the invalid JSON file. But if that's not possible, I guess the replace is needed. But you should use a regular expression so it doesn't replace `\\'` with `\'` -- in this case the first backslash is escaping the second backslash, they're not escaping the quote. A negative lookbehind will prevent this.

```
import re
newstring = re.sub(r"(?<!\\)\\'", "'", originalstring)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not bad. It seems ugly because the problem is ugly - you have corrupt data. It's certainly simple, elegant, and effective. It will only fail if the substring `\\'` (that's three characters, I'm not escaping anything) is present anywhere, and even then only if the number of consecutive slashes is even. So your options are:

1. Just do your current thing, but first check `if r"\\'" in originalstring` and throw an error if so. Easy, safe, probably fine.
2. Use a regex with a negative lookbehind for `(\\\\)+` or something.
3. Catch errors and use the attributes of the errors to decide on a portion of the string to replace.

Check out this snippet:

```
import json
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

s = r'"\'"'
print(s)
try:
    print(json.loads(s))
except JSONDecodeError as e:
    print(vars(e))
```

Output:

```
"\'"
{'msg': 'Invalid \\escape', 'colno': 2, 'doc': '"\\\'"', 'pos': 1, 'lineno': 1}
```

Comment: Only in Python 3 does the exception have those attributes; in Python 2 all you'll get is a `ValueError` exception, and you are stuck with parsing the text message for this info.

Comment: You can use `json.JSONDecodeError` by the way, you don't need to import it from `json.decoder`.

Comment: Yes, Python 2 gives me a `ValueError: Invalid \escape`: