# Could not convert json string to array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need one help. I am unable to convert string to json array using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$education=$_POST['education'];
```

the above line give this output `[{'name':'aaa','id':'12'},{'name':'bbb','id':'20'}]`. But its coming as a string .I tried to convert into array like below but it gived output as null

```
$edu=json_decode($education,true);
print_r($edu);
```

It gives the empty output. Here I need to convert it to array and populate all data. Please help me.

Comment: Use double quote for json and try

[{"name":"aaa","id":"12"},{"name":"bbb","id":"20"}]

Comment: The JSON string has the wrong quotes. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response), only double quotes are allowed.

Comment: Not a valid JSON click [here](https://jsonlint.com/?json=[{'name':'aaa','id':'12'},{'name':'bbb','id':'20'}]) @user6838959 JSON is passed valid test [here](https://jsonlint.com/?json=[{"name":"aaa","id":"12"},{"name":"bbb","id":"20"}])

Answer (score 1):

Hi You need to make your json string like below:

```
$arr = '[{"name":"aaa","id":"12"},{"name":"bbb","id":"20"}]';
$a = json_decode($arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
die;
```

it will show your output like below:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => aaa
        [id] => 12
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => bbb
        [id] => 20
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can use this function to check valid json:

```
function _isJsonString($string) {
        json_decode($string);
        return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
    }
```

You can also check online for valid json: http://json.parser.online.fr/
Hope this will help.